# What are the activation functions that can get 2 answers?

Tags: machine-learning, conv-neural-network, activation-function

I have an algorithm that reads a 4X4 grid with a shape on one of the cells.
I am trying to develop a CNN algorithm where it could know what the shape is and where it is.
The following would be the possible outputs

```
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
```

Where the first four values would show what the object is (triangle, circle, star, square) and the last sixteen values would show where the object lies in the 4x4 square, so the first value would be (1,1) the second (1,2), etc.

I am having a difficult time trying to find an activation function that would show the above. I know that softmax does not work as it is constrained to the sum of all values being 1. I guess what I would like is to get an activation function that would work like softmax that where the sum of all values would become 2, or I would like to get something that would use 2 softmax activation function. I was wondering if anybody knew what activation function I needed to use.

Answer (score 0):

Separate your matrix into two outputs: one for the classes and one for the positions.

On the first four parameters use Cross-Entropy Loss. This is because your shape can only be one of the four classes (triangle, circle, star, square). The LogSoftmax or Softmax activation function is suitable.

On the remaining parameters, I don't fully understand what characteristics you need so it's hard to recommend. Is it correct that you want to produce a prediction of which of the possible positions the shape lies at, and it can only be in one of them for a given input? If so, use the same loss and activation function on this second output.

Sum the two losses before back-propagation.

---

**Reference**

https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/a-model-with-multiple-outputs/10440/2